# Question about Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_2)$ be normed spaces, and $X\subset Y$. If each $f\in (X,\|\cdot\|_1)^\ast$ extends to a bounded linear functional in $(Y,\|\cdot\|_2)^\ast$ with same norm, then $(X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is a subspace of $(Y,\|\cdot\|_2)$, i.e., for all $x\in X$, $\|x\|_1=\|x\|_2$.

I only proved that $\|x\|_1\leq\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in X$. I am in a difficult condition to prove $\|x\|_1\geq\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in X$.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a counterexample: Let $Y=(R^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ and $X=(R,\frac{1}{2}|\cdot|)$. For each linear functional $f=\langle a,\cdot\rangle$ on $X$, there is an extension $g=\langle a,\sqrt{3}a \rangle$ on $Y$ and $\|f\|=\|g\|$.

Comment: sorry, $g=\langle a,\sqrt{3}a \rangle$.

Comment: How is $g$ and extension of $f$? Your definition of $g$ is a constant.

Comment: You mean $g(x)=\langle(a,\sqrt{3}a),x\rangle$.

Comment: g maps $(x,y)\in Y$ to what?

Comment: yes, $g=(a,\sqrt{a})\in R^n=(R^n)^*$, which maps $(x,y)$ to $ax+\sqrt{a}y$.

Comment: sorry. $g=(a,\sqrt{3}a)$ and maps $(x,y)$ to $ax+\sqrt{3}ay$

Comment: it's $R^2$ but $R^n$

Comment: @luozhenghua: You can edit your answer to correct the mistakes instead of writing them into comments.